# Pass a complex struct to the Windows API

Tags: winapi, raku, kernel32, nativecall

I am trying to use the `GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(HANDLE, PCONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO)` function from the Windows API using Perl 6 and (of course) NativeCall.

I think I have set up the `CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO` struct the function needs correctly, but the code crashes after the call when I try to dump its content.

This is the shortest (not quite but close) way to demonstrate the problem:

```
use NativeCall;

constant \HANDLE            := Pointer[void];
constant \SHORT             := int16;
constant \USHORT            := uint16;
constant \WORD              := uint16;
constant \DWORD             := uint32;
constant \BOOL              := int32;
constant \STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE := -11;
constant \STD_INPUT_HANDLE  := -10;

class COORD is repr('CStruct')            {
  has SHORT $.X;
  has SHORT $.Y;
}

class SMALL_RECT is repr("CStruct")            {
  has SHORT $.Left;
  has SHORT $.Top;
  has SHORT $.Right;
  has SHORT $.Bottom;
};

class CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO is repr("CStruct")            {
  has COORD $.dwSize;
  has COORD $.dwCursorPosition;
  has WORD $.wAttributes;
  has SMALL_RECT $.srWindow;
  has COORD $.dwMaximumWindowSize;

  submethod TWEAK {
    $!dwSize := COORD.new;
    $!dwCursorPosition := COORD.new;
    $!srWindow := SMALL_RECT.new;
    $!dwMaximumWindowSize := COORD.new;
  }
}

# C: BOOL WINAPI GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(_In_  HANDLE hConsoleOutput, _Out_ PCONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO lpConsoleScreenBufferInfo);
sub GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(HANDLE, CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO is rw) is native("Kernel32.dll") returns BOOL { * };
sub GetStdHandle(DWORD) is native('Kernel32') returns Pointer[void]  { * };

my CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO
  $info = CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO.new;

my HANDLE
  $handle-o = GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE );

dd $info;
say "GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo ", GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo( $handle-o, $info );
say "Will I live?";
dd $info; #crashes without notice
```

Any hints as to why the crash occurs and how to fix it are very welcome.

Comment: It crashes as soon as I try to access anything. dd was just exemplary.

Comment: `constant \STD_INPUT_HANDLE  := -10;` presumably binds an `Int`, with `is repr('P6Int')`, to `STD_INPUT_HANDLE`. And in `GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE )` that gets used to bind to a 32 bit `DWORD`. Does Rakudo automatically coerce or whatever has to be done to make that work?

Comment: Yes, that works transparently. I use another handle that I obtain in the same way for input and that works fine. The problem must be in GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo

Comment: I probably need to use "Pointer" somehow. I will look into it again tomorrow.

Comment: Do you really need `TWEAK` method? Whole structure is overwritten by `GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo`. I don't know how Perl works internally, maybe it adds vtable which is overwriten by API call. In C++ for example you can't add virtual methods because they could need additional storage for vtable pointer.

Comment: The attribute declaration probably should read `HAS SMALL_RECT $.srWindow;`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use `HAS` instead of `has` for the members of `CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO` that are structures as these are embedded instead of referenced by pointer (which is the Perl6 default).

Once you do that, you can drop the `TWEAK` as well so the code will read

```
class CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO is repr("CStruct") {
  HAS COORD $.dwSize;
  HAS COORD $.dwCursorPosition;
  has WORD $.wAttributes;
  HAS SMALL_RECT $.srWindow;
  HAS COORD $.dwMaximumWindowSize;
}
```